# "java.lang.Exception: Did not find any pact files for provider..." between Java8 and Node

Tags: java, node.js, angular, typescript, pact

I'm trying to run the pact test between **Java8 (provider)** and **Node (consumer)** and I have an exception that is being very hard to fix. Actually, when I run the provider I get the following error message:

"java.lang.Exception: Did not find any pact files for provider..."

I note that the problem is (maybe) in the pactSpecification key name, generated by the consumer (Node) in the Pact Broker.

```
Ex: 
 "metadata": {
    "pactSpecification": {
      "version": "3.0.0"
    }
  }
```

I ran Pact localy just for testing using @PactUrl, I change the name of key **pactSpecification (camelCase)** for **pact-specification (with dash and lower case)** and....it works!

```
Ex: 
 "metadata": {
    "pact-specification": {
      "version": "3.0.0"
    }
  }
```

**The question is, how to match the metadata key name *"pactSpecification"* or *"pact-specification"* between Java8 and Node? I tried all versions of pact in maven repository but it did not work.**

Actually, in Java 8 environment I'm using Maven 3.5.2 with the following dependencies:

```
<pact.version>3.5.9</pact.version>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
        <artifactId>pact-jvm-consumer-java8_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>${pact.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
        <artifactId>pact-jvm-provider-spring_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>${pact.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
    <artifactId>pact-jvm-provider-maven_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>${pact.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>deploy-contract</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>publish</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <pactBrokerUrl>${pact-broker.url}</pactBrokerUrl>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For the Node environment, I'm using the following dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
   "@pact-foundation/pact": "~6.0.0-alpha.14",
   "@pact-foundation/pact-node": "~6.19.0",
...
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please update to the latest versions of each, as pact-jvm now writes the pact specification version in the correct format (camelcase).

Answer (score 0):

Exact! I changed to the latest version (3.5.21), I updated the Intellij to 2018.2 and it works!

> BugFix 3.15.19: "f71deb21 - fix: pact specification attribute should
>   be in camel case..."
>   https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

There is a bug in the IntelliJ 2017.3 that does not run the tests if the pact version is 3.5.18 or plus.

Thank you!!!!